# how can I implement a function to load data into a design matrix and an output vector in octave

Tags: function, matrix, vector, load, octave

I have a .txt file with dimensions 100x4 but i want to generalise and make an initial matrix with m x n+1 dimension as the code should work fine with any data file. m is the number of training examples and n is the number of training features and the last column is the output vector.

```
function [X,y]= loadData(filename)
data=load(filename);
X=load(filename);
y=load(filename);
m=rows(filename);
n=size(filename);

end
```

expected value of elements in the matrix do not match the found value.
what is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are loading 3 times the same things, so at the end `data`, `X`, and `y` contain exactly the same things.

Then you are passing `filename` -that is a string- to `rows()` and `size()`, so do not expect getting the sizes of some arrays: these functions won't open any file, they just operate on the string in this case. In octave a string is considered as a 1xl matric, l being the length of the string.